# why my urls.py does't work with Django

Tags: django, web, django-urls

Today when I code my blog with 'Building_a_blog_in_30_mins_with_Django_Screencast',I meet some problems.When I click the title with the article，it can't appear the right page.!

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
```

Using the URLconf defined in myblog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^$
^(?P<pk>\d+)/$
^admin/
^admin/doc/
```

The current URL, app/1, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

and it's my urls.py:

```
url(r'^$',ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("created[:2]template_name="                                                                               blog.html")), 
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',DetailView.as_view( model=Post, template_name="post.html")),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls'))
```

I doesn't konw what is going on with it.Please help,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `'app/'` in your url.

```
url(r'^app/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',DetailView.as_view( model=Post, template_name="post.html")),
```

Or may be you need to define these urls in `urls.py` of your app (named `app` ?) and include it in sites main `urls.py`

```
url(r'app/', include('app.urls'))
```

Comment: I just add the url(r'app/', include('app.urls')) in my main urls.py but the error become :Using the URLconf defined in myblog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
   app/