# The urls.py in my app can't be recognized by my main urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [why my urls.py does't work with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766889/why-my-urls-py-doest-work-with-django)

my projec's urls.py is:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',url(r'app/',include('app.urls')),...)
```

(my app just named app),but when I click the browser， It appear 404 error and  says 
 Using the URLconf defined in `myblog.urls`, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
app/
...
```

I don't know why and what's going on!

If you know please tell me.

Thanks

Comment: Problem is probably in app/urls.py can you add that file too.

Comment: thanks you and I have slove the problem.Because I haven't add the 'app.views'in my app's urls.py.But thanks for you help!

Comment: Can you share a snippet of your urls.py? It could be an incorrect regex for all you know